# Remove duplicated value that generated by element data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a group of images, each of the image have `data-type="type,type"`, so in order to make my life easier I intend to grab the data-type, and make them into an array (wrapped each of them in span) and append them to an "category" element.

```js
$('li.grid-item').each(function () {
    // grab a reference to the current li
    var $el = $(this);
    // get the url from its data-class attribute
    var arr = $el.find('img').data('type').split(',');

    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        $el.find('.category').append('<span>' + value + '</span>');
        $el.addClass(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<li class="grid-item">
    <figure>
        <img src="img/sticker/still/sticker_30.png" alt="sticker" title="You know I'm good" data-type="others/" data-price="9 bahts" data-alt="img/sticker/ani/sticker_30.gif" />
    </figure>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="download ala_carte">CONTINUE</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category"></div>
</li>
```

It work fine but duplicated 20 of each value, please help. How to remove those duplicated array value? Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not seeing anything replicating 20x. https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5587/

Comment: What @chungtinhlakho said! Tried this in another fiddle as well, I cannot replicate the issue. It is either some problem with some other code or something else. Provide more info please!

Comment: [link](http://greysaga.com/demo/ms/) I put it here, have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to collect all existing types first in on array (and only add new values to it, if there weren't already existing). Afterwards, you could add span elements for each type. And you should only have one "category" container to list all types.

**Update**

Your function is executed to often (more than 20 times), because you are calling it everytime your $grid.imagesLoaded() makes progress. Call it when you are "done".
Try replacing

```
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress()
```

with

```
$grid.imagesLoaded().done()
```

to call your function only once after all images are loaded. Additionally you could empty the category container before re-filling it.

Comment: Thanks Eytibi, but I don't know how. Please have a look at the [demo](http://greysaga.com/demo/ms/), then you'll know what I mean. I guess... lol

Comment: I guess I found your issue. Your function is executed to often (more than 20 times), because you are calling it everytime your $grid.imagesLoaded() makes progress. Call it when you are "done"

Try replacing "$grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function ()" with "$grid.imagesLoaded().done(function ()"

Additionally you could empty the category container before re-filling it.

Comment: WOW! It WORKS!!!! Thanks!!!! Now how do mark this as my question got answered? Sorry, I'm new, I googled a bit but can find the green checkmark.

Comment: yea got it! Thanks for the help Eytibi.